# curl in Mathematica, google link-shortener

Tags: syntax, wolfram-cloud, web-access, command-line

I want to automatically get short links equivalents for things I `CloudDeploy`. I'd appreciate some tips on integrating command line workflow below into Mathematica function. For command line, using free API [key](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#APIKey), I do

To shorten `www.google.com` on command line, I execute following:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=$key \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}'
```

This will print the following to stdout, thing next to `id` contains the shortened URL.

```
{
 "kind": "urlshortener#url",
 "id": "https://goao.gl/fbsS",
 "longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"
}
```

Comment: I was not aware of URLShorten, that looks like a better solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many `URL*` functions overlap with functionality so there there are many ways.

Here is an example which returns a list of rules:

```
URLExecute @ HTTPRequest[
    "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url"
  , <| "Method" -> "POST"
     , "Headers" -> {"Content-Type" -> "application/json"}
     , "Query" -> {"key" -> key}
     , "Body" -> ExportString[{"longUrl" -> "http://www.google.com/"}, "JSON"]
    |>
  , CharacterEncoding -> None (*becasue export to json already did it*)
]
```

> ```
> {"kind" -> "urlshortener#url", "id" -> ..., 
>  "longUrl" -> "http://www.google.com/"}
> ```

But, as mentioned earlier, you can use WRI's shortener with `URLShorten`.