# Can't get a POST URL working with HTTPRequest

Tags: web-access, url

I'm puzzled by the syntax of building a URL with HTTPRequest.
I can build a URL POST request with postman and that works perfectly.
The HTTP code that is build with Postman is:

POST /rest/login-sessions HTTP/1.1

Host: myhost
Accept: application/json

X-API-Version: 200

Content-Type: application/json

Cache-Control: no-cache

Postman-Token: 0408e579-7571-fd08-fa7c-4bf16ea70a3d

{

"userName":"administrator",

"password":"xxx"

}

With Mathematica 11.1.1.0 on Windows 10 I try:

```
header = "Headers" -> {"Accept" -> "application/json", 
   "X-API-Version" -> "200", "Content-Type" -> "application/json"}
body = "Body" -> {"userName" -> "administrator", 
   "password" -> "xxx"}

gettoken = 
 HTTPRequest[
  "https://myhost/rest/login-sessions", <|Method -> "POST",
   header, body|>, VerifySecurityCertificates -> False]
```

With URLRead I get

```
URLRead[gettoken]["Body"]
```

Output:

"{\"errorSource\":null,\"nestedErrors\":[],\"details\":\"The JSON \
sent in the request is malformed and cannot be parsed. There is an \
error on line 1 near column 0.\",\"recommendedActions\":[\"Correct \
the malformed JSON and try the request \
again.\"],\"data\":{},\"errorCode\":\"MALFORMED_JSON\",\"message\":\"\
Malformed JSON cannot be parsed.\"}"

So it seems that the JSON format is wrong but I can't find a way to see how it's build. When I use the token generated through Postman I can build valid GET requests so that works perfectly fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to ExportString the body to Json.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144405/integrating-link-shortener-with-clouddeploy/144449#144449

Comment: @Kuba, I wish I posted this question before :). Thanks! I don't find this obvious reading through the documentation.

Comment: I'm glad it works. I have marked it a duplicate because both are in essence about correct http request syntax. Let me know if you disagree.

Comment: @Kuba No problem. I did already see that post but even then it didn't sink in :)..

Answer (score 4):

```
"Body" -> 
 ExportString[<|"userName" -> "administrator", 
   "password" -> "xxx"|>, "JSON"]
```

Thanks to Kuba!