# Querying the Monero blockchain via JSON-RPC

Tags: json-format

When querying [Monero deamon](https://getmonero.org/getting-started/running) via JSON-RPC as described in [Daemon RPC documentation](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/daemon-rpc), via Curl, everithing pass fine :

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/json_rpc -d "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":\"0\",\"method\":\"getblockcount\"}" -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

internal `\"` is escaped double quote.
 Return:

```
{
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "count": 1313381,
    "status": "OK"
  }
}
```

But when I try similar in Mathematica:

```
URLFetch["http://127.0.0.1:18081/json_rpc", Method -> "POST", 
 "Parameters" -> {"jsonrpc" -> "2.0", "id" -> "0", 
   "method" -> "getblockcount"}, 
 "Headers" -> {"Content-Type" -> "application/json"}]
```

Mathematica returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": -32700,
    "message": "Parse error"
  },
  "id": 0,
  "jsonrpc": ""
}
```

and Monero deamon reports log error:

```
2017-05-19 09:18:56.657 [RPC1]  ERROR   net.http        contrib/epee/include/storages/portable_storage_from_json.h:83   Wrong JSON character at: jsonrpc=2.0&id=0&method=getblockcount
2017-05-19 09:18:56.657 [RPC1]  ERROR   net.http        contrib/epee/include/storages/portable_storage_from_json.h:368  Failed to parse json, what: Wrong JSON character at: jsonrpc=2.0&id=0&method=getblockcount
```

please help with aranging JSON-RPC query string in Mathematica for querying Monero blockchain deamon.

**NOTE**: *If you go to try with Monero deamon, as I described, you konw that deamon will download full blockchain that is about 16GB in size on your local storage.*

Comment: What comes after `-d` is a Body/Content, not parameters. See [144449](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144449/5478), does `"Body" -> 
 ExportString[{"jsonrpc" -> "2.0", "id" -> "0", 
   "method" -> "getblockcount"}, "JSON"]` work?

Comment: @Kuba, yes, thank you.